# How can I show/hide one <div> when a radio button is clicked on, when all the <div>s have the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have this JavaScript code:

```
$("#midden-offertes form .subvragen").hide();

$("#midden-offertes form .veld .radio :radio").change(function() 
{
    if (this.value === 'Ja')
    { 
        $("#midden-offertes form .subvragen",this).show()
    }
    else
    {
        $("#midden-offertes form .subvragen",this).hide();
    }
});
```

I also have a `<form>` with different radio buttons. When I click on a radio button, the `.subvragen` `<div>` must be shown.

But every `.radio` button has its own `.subvragen` `<div>`. How can I change this JavaScript code so that only the `.subvragen` within each radio button is shown when I click on that radio button?

When I click on a radio button now, all the `.subvragen` `<div>`s are shown.

**Edit:**
I have uploaded the files. You can see them here: http://mikevierwind.nl/karel/offerterelatie.html

Comment: We need to get the relation between radio button and the div. It could be better if you can post your HTML snippet.

Comment: http://mikevierwind.nl/karel/offerterelatie.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the HTML you’ve got](http://mikevierwind.nl/karel/offerterelatie.html), you could use the following JavaScript (I think):

```
$("#midden-offertes form .veld .radio :radio").change(function() 
{
    var $subvragen = $(this).parents('.veld').siblings('.subvragen');

    if (this.value === 'Ja')
    { 
        $subvragen.show();
    }
    else
    {
        $subvragen.hide();
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you could add `id` attributes to your `subvragen` `<div>`s and radios, you could use them — it’d make the JavaScript less reliant on the HTML nesting.

E.g. if your HTML were like this:

```
<div id="midden-offertes">
    <form>
        <div class="veld">
            <div class="radio">
                <input name="geoff" id="geoff_1" value="a" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subvragen" id="subvragen_geoff_1"></div>

        <div class="veld">
            <div class="radio">
                <input name="geoff" id="geoff_2" value="b" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subvragen" id="subvragen_geoff_2"></div>

        <div class="veld">
            <div class="radio">
                <input name="geoff" id="geoff_3" value="c" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subvragen" id="subvragen_geoff_3"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then your JavaScript would go something like this:

```
$("#midden-offertes form .subvragen").hide();

$("#midden-offertes form .veld .radio :radio").change(function() 
{
    if (this.value === 'Ja')
    { 
        $(".subvragen#subvragen_" + this.id).show()
    }
    else
    {
        $(".subvragen#subvragen_" + this.id).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: If id is given then there is no need for any other selector.

Comment: @rahul: very true. Edited accordingly. (Of course, it now assumes that the HTML is authored correctly, i.e. with no duplicate `id`s.)